# Can you run OS X on an Amazon EC2 instance?

Tags: mac-osx, amazon-ec2

Can you run OS X on an Amazon EC2 instance? It'd be nice to "rent" an OS X computer.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

OS X isn't listed as an instance type so I don't think you can. On top of that you can't legally run OS X on anything but Apple hardware.

There are companies that you can get monthly plans to run OS X if you [search for them](http://www.godaddy.com/hosting/mac-hosting.aspx).

Comment: What Iain said: You can technically run OS X on all kinds of hardware, but legally speaking it may only be run on Genuine Apple Hardware.  Amazon would probably love to offer you the option to rent an OS X computer, but they won't risk running afoul of Apple's den of lawyers to do it :)